# Computing Length of line using structures and functions

Tags: c++, function, struct, structure, line

Okay so I have been given a Pseducode and have been asked to follow it, i have done it accordingly but still get stuck and get errors any help?

Heres my main function,(not allowed to change this)

```
int main()
{
    // TODO: implement functions: getLine() and computeLength(Line)
    Line line1 = getLine();
    double length = computeLength(line1);
    std::cout << "The lenthg of this line is " << length << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Create a point struct type that stores x, y coordinates of an individual point

```
struct Point
{
    double X;
    double Y;
}point;
```

Create a line struct type that stores two points (start and end)

```
struct Line
{
    Point start;
    Point end;
}pt1, pt2;
```

Create a function that retrieves a point struct based on the user input

```
Point getLine()
{
    cout << "Please enter the X, Y coordinates for the point: ";
    cin >> point.X >> point.Y ;
    return point;
}
```

Create a function that computes the length of the line provided by the user

```
double computeLength(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2)
{
    double D;
    D = sqrt(pow(pt1.X - pt2.X, 2) + pow(pt1.Y - pt2.Y, 2));
    return D;
}
```

What am I doing wrong??
When i run it i get this error

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Point' to 'Line' 

Error   2   error C2660: 'computeLength' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

Comment: We can't really know what you're doing wrong, unless you tells us what happens when you run your code. Does it fail to build? If so, what are the errors? Does it crash when you run it? Of so, then run in a debugger. Does it output the wrong values? If so, then tell us the expected and actual output for some input.

Comment: However, to start with, your `getLine` function doesn't get a *line* but a *point*.

Comment: i edited it above, to show the errors

Comment: Read the declarations of the functions and then look at how you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the function according the call, like that:

```
Line getLine()
{
    Line line;
    cout << "Please enter the X, Y coordinates for the start point: ";
    cin >> line.start.X >> line.start.Y ;
    cout << "Please enter the X, Y coordinates for the end point: ";
    cin >> line.end.X >> line.end.Y ;
    return line;
}

double computeLength(const Line& line)
{
    double D;
    D = sqrt(pow(line.end.X - line.start.X, 2) + pow(line.end.Y - line.start.Y, 2));
    return D;
}
```

Comment: i am not allowed to change the main function.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim is right.

Error 1 is caused by `Line line1 = getLine(...)`.  This is because despite the name you gave it getLine gets a point.  Don't change that line.  Change the definition of getLine to return a Line.

```
Line getLine()
{
    Line line;
    Point point1;
    Point point2;

    cout << "Please enter the X, Y coordinates for the first point: ";
    cin >> point1.X >> point1.Y ;
    line.start = point1;

    cout << "Please enter the X, Y coordinates for the second point: ";
    cin >> point2.X >> point2.Y ;
    line.end = point2;

    return line;
}
```

Error 2 is caused by `double length = computeLength(line1);` because you fed computeLength a line but defined it to take 2 points.  I say make it work with a line.

```
double computeLength(const Line& line)
{
    double D;
    Point pt1 = line.start;
    Point pt2 = line.end;
    D = sqrt(pow(pt1.X - pt2.X, 2) + pow(pt1.Y - pt2.Y, 2));
    return D;
}
```

Comment: if i do this i get Error 2 error C2228: left of '.start' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Try it with `Line line;` added to the top of getLine.  Variables work better when they've been declared.